# vertical alignment between two columns with \vspace's

Tags: multicol, vspace, obeylines

i'm using a `\vspace` to make empty lines. I need to find a way so that the space between two lines separated by such an empty line equals the space between two lines with one non-empty line in between. Here is my mwe. I use `multicol` to make a two columns document. I'm surprised that even before the occurrence of a `\vspace` near the top of the page misalignment is noticeable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=20mm,
                    vmargin=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace,multicol}

\changefontsize{12}
%\setstretch{1.4}

\newcommand{\emptyline}{
  \vspace {1.0\baselineskip}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{obeylines}
Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
necessitatibus nulla qui.

Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi quam
commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
Debitis accusantium et porro

et libero nulla ut est.
Asperiores sed exercitationem aut.
Ex sapiente cumque cum non
nesciunt eos nostrum dolore.

Quia deserunt
repellat sunt quo voluptatem.
Nesciunt hic tenetur vel
sapiente.

Debitis nobis fugiat
doloremque voluptates enim ratione.
Unde magni beatae magni.

Unde voluptatum qui odio corporis
quia. Perferendis dolorum eum
doloremque minima et.

Quam vitae culpa recusandae
molestiae vero fugit. Rerum
eum quaerat et omnis. Facilis
sed dolorum veniam in
adipisci nostrum.

\emptyline
Facere assumenda rerum tempora
corporis atque ut quod.
Beatae alias autem quae quis
blanditiis ratione.
Fugiat et est neque omnis.
Eaque quia porro suscipit
voluptatem ducimus corporis.

\emptyline
Alias reiciendis id aut labore
autem. Unde reprehenderit ut
dolores. Est animi laborum

sequi eos soluta sed aut
maxime. At totam et non
et. Quia quia iste ut.

Consequatur quia aperiam maiores
ducimus repellendus. Sed sed
non velit aut quia consequuntur.

\emptyline
Quam perspiciatis eius quos
nihil quas. Quibusdam tenetur
quis eius asperiores laudantium.

Dolor veritatis aut dignissimos.
Assumenda ab repudiandae
tempora est officia laborum.

\emptyline
Sint blanditiis inventore
voluptatem perspiciatis.
Vitae est sint labore dolorem
ducimus voluptas quia.

Omnis expedita et non voluptas
nam.
  \end{obeylines}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try to use `verbatim` environment or load [fancyvbr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) and get access to  a more adjustable `Verbatim`. In both cases, you would need to redefine the default font to `\rmfamily`. The latter case is explained in the manual. For a built-in case, you would need to add this to preamble: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\rmfamily}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the flexibility from `\parskip`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=20mm,
                    vmargin=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace,multicol}

\changefontsize{12}
%\setstretch{1.4}

\newcommand{\emptyline}{%
  \vspace {1.0\baselineskip}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{obeylines}
Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
necessitatibus nulla qui.

Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi quam
commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
Debitis accusantium et porro

et libero nulla ut est.
Asperiores sed exercitationem aut.
Ex sapiente cumque cum non
nesciunt eos nostrum dolore.

Quia deserunt
repellat sunt quo voluptatem.
Nesciunt hic tenetur vel
sapiente.

Debitis nobis fugiat
doloremque voluptates enim ratione.
Unde magni beatae magni.

Unde voluptatum qui odio corporis
quia. Perferendis dolorum eum
doloremque minima et.

Quam vitae culpa recusandae
molestiae vero fugit. Rerum
eum quaerat et omnis. Facilis
sed dolorum veniam in
adipisci nostrum.

\emptyline
Facere assumenda rerum tempora
corporis atque ut quod.
Beatae alias autem quae quis
blanditiis ratione.
Fugiat et est neque omnis.
Eaque quia porro suscipit
voluptatem ducimus corporis.

\emptyline
Alias reiciendis id aut labore
autem. Unde reprehenderit ut
dolores. Est animi laborum

sequi eos soluta sed aut
maxime. At totam et non
et. Quia quia iste ut.

Consequatur quia aperiam maiores
ducimus repellendus. Sed sed
non velit aut quia consequuntur.

\emptyline
Quam perspiciatis eius quos
nihil quas. Quibusdam tenetur
quis eius asperiores laudantium.

Dolor veritatis aut dignissimos.
Assumenda ab repudiandae
tempora est officia laborum.

\emptyline
Sint blanditiis inventore\llap{\rule[.2pt]{15cm}{.2pt}}
voluptatem perspiciatis.
Vitae est sint labore dolorem
ducimus voluptas quia.

Omnis expedita et non voluptas
nam.
  \end{obeylines}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Although as you are already using `obeylines` I would probably have not used a  `\emptyline` command at all and simply made a blank line in the source separate the verses.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[verbose,hmargin=20mm,
                    vmargin=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontsize,fix-cm}
\usepackage{setspace,multicol}

\changefontsize{12}
%\setstretch{1.4}


\protected\gdef\obeyedline{\par\mbox{}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{obeylines}
Adipisci fuga et quis dicta est et
odit. Illo aut nulla qui incidunt
necessitatibus nulla qui.

Sunt cumque voluptatem quasi quam
commodi culpa quaerat sunt.
Debitis accusantium et porro

et libero nulla ut est.
Asperiores sed exercitationem aut.
Ex sapiente cumque cum non
nesciunt eos nostrum dolore.

Quia deserunt
repellat sunt quo voluptatem.
Nesciunt hic tenetur vel
sapiente.

Debitis nobis fugiat
doloremque voluptates enim ratione.
Unde magni beatae magni.

Unde voluptatum qui odio corporis
quia. Perferendis dolorum eum
doloremque minima et.

Quam vitae culpa recusandae
molestiae vero fugit. Rerum
eum quaerat et omnis. Facilis
sed dolorum veniam in
adipisci nostrum.

Facere assumenda rerum tempora
corporis atque ut quod.
Beatae alias autem quae quis
blanditiis ratione.
Fugiat et est neque omnis.
Eaque quia porro suscipit
voluptatem ducimus corporis.

Alias reiciendis id aut labore
autem. Unde reprehenderit ut
dolores. Est animi laborum

sequi eos soluta sed aut
maxime. At totam et non
et. Quia quia iste ut.

Consequatur quia aperiam maiores
ducimus repellendus. Sed sed
non velit aut quia consequuntur.

Quam perspiciatis eius quos
nihil quas. Quibusdam tenetur
quis eius asperiores laudantium.

Dolor veritatis aut dignissimos.
Assumenda ab repudiandae
tempora est officia laborum.

Sint blanditiis inventore\llap{\rule[.2pt]{15cm}{.2pt}}
voluptatem perspiciatis.
Vitae est sint labore dolorem
ducimus voluptas quia.

Omnis expedita et non voluptas
nam.
  \end{obeylines}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's an mwe. The actual code is somewhat different.

Comment: @user1850133 sure, but hopefully the answer still applies.

Comment: Did you try David Carlisle answer? If so do you still have a problem? If you did not, why not?

Comment: yes it works. I did thiis mwe thinking that its fix would fix the original code. But it doesn't. That code uses some `vtop` and heights are determined by some macro. It seems the problem is there. (666417)

Comment: @user1850133 it happens, hard to make a good mwe until after you know the answer. If this answers the question as asked the thing to do is accept this to finish this post, it may help someone, then  you can ask a new question with whatever extra feature you need to ask.

Comment: i tried your solution using `\protected\gdef\obeyelines{\par\mbox{}}` with a foreign script (devanagari), i had to increase the `baselineskip` to something above 16pt.